# Is there a function in PySpark similar to the re.findall() function of python?

Tags: regex, apache-spark, pyspark

For an assignment I need to extract all "mentions" in a comment. In plain python I would do something like this:

```
string = "@rjberger10 @geneh19 home"
re.findall(r'@\w+', string)
```

This would give me an array like this: ['@rjberger10', '@geneh19']. However the assignment states that we have to use the PySpark way, but I can't find a function in PySpark similar to findall(). The closest I got was this:

```
result = dict_comments[13].withColumn("@tjes", regexp_extract(col("Text"), r'(@\w+)', 0))
```

However this only gives me the first time an @ is used, so when there are multiple mentions I only find one.

Answer (score 2):

I have an approach using `explode`, `split`, `regexp_extract` and `collect_list`.

```py
re_df = spark._sc.parallelize([[1,"@rjberger10"], 
                               [2,"@geneh19"],
                               [3,"home"],
                               [4,"@geneh19 @rjberger10"]]).toDF(["id","test_string"])


temp_column_name = "explode_on_split"

(
    re_df.withColumn(temp_column_name, 
                     f.explode(f.split(f.col("test_string"), " "))) 
         .withColumn('extract', 
                     f.regexp_extract(f.col(temp_column_name), r'(@\w+)', 1))
         .groupBy(f.col('test_string'))
         .agg(
           f.collect_list(f.col('extract')).alias('final_extract'))
).show()

+--------------------+--------------------+
|         test_string|       final_extract|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|@geneh19 @rjberger10|[@geneh19, @rjber...|
|         @rjberger10|       [@rjberger10]|
|                home|                  []|
|            @geneh19|          [@geneh19]|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

I know this looks cumbersome, so to explain: 
I am splitting on space, exploding the output into rows, regex-extracing the output and collecting in this order. 
However, if you look at the Spark GitHub page, you can expect this function to pop-up very soon as there's already an open PR (https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/21985). 
Hope this helps!

Comment: The `explode` + `agg` is very expensive. You're likely better of just using a `udf`. Although, for spark 2.4+ there might be a way to do `split` + [`filter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#filter)...

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be to first remove the parts of your string that doesn't match the pattern and then split the remaining text on whitespace:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, split, regexp_replace

df.withColumn(
    "@tjes", 
    split(regexp_replace(col("Text"), r'(\s|^)[^@]\w+(\s|$)', ''), '\s+')
).show(truncate=False)
#+-------------------------+-----------------------+
#|Text                     |@tjes                  |
#+-------------------------+-----------------------+
#|@rjberger10 @geneh19 home|[@rjberger10, @geneh19]|
#+-------------------------+-----------------------+
```

The pattern used in the `regexp_replace` is:

- `(\s|^)`: Whitespace or start of string
- `[^@]`: Not the `@` character
- `\w+`: Any number of word characters
- `(\s|$)`: Whitespace or end of string

Comment: This still gives only the first occurence. Using a UDF solved my problem.

Comment: @TiboGeysen , can you share what udf you used to resolve the problem?